# Complex RANK in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a complex query which is really over the top of my head.
I think RANK of the RANK-ing is needed, but there must be a better, and an existing way.

Here I have a simpe table:

```
Manufacturer    DateOF  Status              Prefer
Dell            05-2014 ComputerInstalled   30
Dell            05-2014 ComputerUninstalled 70
Dell            05-2014 ComputerUninstalled 70
Dell            05-2014 ComputerUninstalled 70
Dell            05-2014 ComputerInstalled   30
Dell            05-2014 ComputerUninstalled 70
Dell            05-2014 ComputerNew         26
Dell            05-2014 ComputerNew         26
Dell            05-2014 ComputerInstalled   30
Dell            05-2014 ComputerInstalled   30
```

What I need to do is to GROUP BY the table by MANUFACTURER and DATEOF columns,
then choose the rows with the lowest PREFER number (26 in this case).

Its easy with RANK function:

```
SELECT sq.*
FROM
(
SELECT
*,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Manufacturer,DateOF ORDER BY Prefer) AS RankPrefer
FROM
table1
WHERE
RankPrefer = 1
) sq
```

So I will have the result of 2 rows with Status ComputerNew.

```
Manufacturer    DateOF  Status              Prefer
Dell            05-2014 ComputerNew         26
Dell            05-2014 ComputerNew         26
```

Thats easy, and not the question.

**The question is:**

I have to implement the following rule:

If the rows with the lowest **Prefer** values (e.g.: 26)
turn out to have **ComputerNew** value in their **Status** field,
then I have to include more rows with **ComputerInstalled** values.

The result should be this:

```
Manufacturer    DateOF  Status              Prefer
Dell            05-2014 ComputerInstalled   30
Dell            05-2014 ComputerInstalled   30
Dell            05-2014 ComputerNew         26
Dell            05-2014 ComputerNew         26
Dell            05-2014 ComputerInstalled   30
Dell            05-2014 ComputerInstalled   30
```

Similar to this rule, I have one more:

If the rows with the lowest **Prefer** values (e.g.: 26)
turn out to have **ComputerOld** value in their **Status** field,
then I have to include more rows with **ComputerUninstalled** values.

I think RANK of RANKING would solve this, but now I am really lost.

Any help is appreciated on this riddle.

Thank you

---

**Edit1:**

Gordon's solution is almost good, but not perfect.

I give you more test data, there you can see where it fails.
SQLFiddle to test is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/527f6/1).

I include the test data here as well:

```
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP10011','04/01/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP10011','04/04/2014','ComputerOld',26)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP10011','04/04/2014','ComputerOld',26)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP10011','04/30/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP10011','05/23/2014','QuickDispose',10)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP10011','06/03/2014','QuickDispose',10)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP10077','04/01/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','04/25/2014','QuickDispose',10)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/02/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP1910','05/02/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/07/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/07/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/07/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/07/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/07/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/07/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/08/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/08/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/08/2014','ComputerInstalled',30)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','05/08/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','06/06/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','06/06/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','06/10/2014','ComputerOld',26)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','06/10/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','06/10/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','06/11/2014','ComputerOld',26)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','06/11/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('HP3720','06/11/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70)
```

The query returns both rows ComputerInstalled and ComputerUninstalled
for the following data:

```
'HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerInstalled',30
'HP1910','05/01/2014','ComputerUninstalled',70
```

It should choose ComputerInstalled only, because for that Manufacturer, in the same month, it should choose the lowest Prefer (30).

The result for this dataset should be this:

```
Manufacturer    DateOF  Status          Prefer
HP10011 2014-04-01  ComputerUninstalled 70
HP10011 2014-04-04  ComputerOld         26
HP10011 2014-04-04  ComputerOld         26
HP10011 2014-04-30  ComputerUninstalled 70
HP10011 2014-05-23  QuickDispose        10
HP10011 2014-06-03  QuickDispose        10
HP10077 2014-04-01  ComputerUninstalled 70
HP1910  2014-04-25  QuickDispose        10
HP1910  2014-05-01  ComputerInstalled   30
HP1910  2014-05-01  ComputerInstalled   30
HP1910  2014-05-01  ComputerInstalled   30
HP1910  2014-05-01  ComputerInstalled   30
HP3720  2014-05-07  ComputerInstalled   30
HP3720  2014-05-07  ComputerInstalled   30
HP3720  2014-05-08  ComputerInstalled   30
HP3720  2014-05-08  ComputerInstalled   30
HP3720  2014-05-08  ComputerInstalled   30
HP3720  2014-06-06  ComputerUninstalled 70
HP3720  2014-06-06  ComputerUninstalled 70
HP3720  2014-06-10  ComputerOld         26
HP3720  2014-06-10  ComputerUninstalled 70
HP3720  2014-06-10  ComputerUninstalled 70
HP3720  2014-06-11  ComputerOld         26
HP3720  2014-06-11  ComputerUninstalled 70
HP3720  2014-06-11  ComputerUninstalled 70
```

Comment: You write, you have to include more rows. But based on which condition? Have you to include the next rows, where the Prefer value is the second greater than the lowest and Status=ComputerInstalled"?

Comment: @derstauner Answers below could help you. So more rows inserted only in two cases: 1. When the rows with lowest Prefer happen to have ComputerOld in their Status field (then include rows with ComputerUninstalled in their Status field) 2. Same logic but with ComputerNew and ComputerInstalled calues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one idea.  Figure out the preference ranking for the rows.  Then get determine whether the rows with rank = 1 meet your criteria using `exists`.

The final query would look like:

```
with r as (
      select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by manufacturer, dateof order by Prefer) as seqnum
      from table1 t
     ),
     r1 as (
      select r.*
      from r
      where seqnum = 1
     )
select r.*
from r
where r.seqnum = 1 or
      (exists (select 1 from r1 where status = 'ComputerNew' and r1.dateof = r.dateof) and r.status = 'ComputerInstalled' or
       exists (select 1 from r1 where status = 'ComputerOld' and r1.dateof = r.dateof) and r.status = 'ComputerUninstalled'
      );
```

Comment: For some reason, it won't let me save changes, so I'll add this in the comments: This solution should work, but I'd recommend surrounded each of the last two lines in the final WHERE clause with parentheses for clarity, rather than relying on operator precedence.  Also, you're referencing the wrong alias in the last select.  It should be `r.*`, not `t.*`.

Comment: Additionally, you only need to select the 'Status' column in the r1 CTE.  Overall though, I think this answer is a great way to solve the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Your solution is almost good, but I cannot figure out why it fails in certain cases. I have edited my Question with Edit1 section, where I create an SQL Fiddle, and supply the test data.

Comment: @JonSenchyna Thank you for the hints! Gordon's solution is almost good, so i have extended my question with an example where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, now that you've made some edits to the question, I have a different answer that I believe will resolve the question.  Here is the query:

```
;with r as (
      select t.*,
             CAST(MONTH(dateof) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(dateof) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS EffDate,
             rank() over (partition by manufacturer, CAST(MONTH(dateof) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(dateof) AS VARCHAR(4)) order by Prefer) as seqnum
      from Table1 t
     ),
     r1 as (
      select r.*
      from r
      where seqnum = 1
     )
select r.*
from r
where r.seqnum = 1 
or
(
  r.Status = 'ComputerUninstalled' and 
  exists ( Select 1 
           from  r1 
           where r1.Manufacturer = r.Manufacturer
           and   r1.EffDate = r.EffDate
           and   r1.Status = 'ComputerOld' )
  and   r.seqNum = ( Select Min(SeqNum) From r as r2
                      Where r2.Manufacturer = r.Manufacturer
                      And   r2.EffDate = r.EffDate
                      And   r2.SeqNum > 1 )          
)
or
(
  r.Status = 'ComputerInstalled' and 
  exists ( Select 1 
           from  r1 
           where r1.Manufacturer = r.Manufacturer
           and   r1.EffDate = r.EffDate
           and   r1.Status = 'ComputerNew' )
  and   r.seqNum = ( Select Min(SeqNum) From r as r2
                      Where r2.Manufacturer = r.Manufacturer
                      And   r2.EffDate = r.EffDate
                      And   r2.SeqNum > 1 )          
);
```

Note:  I get 2 more records than your expected resultset indicates.  But from what you described, I believe that you made a mistake in your expected results.  There are 6 "ComputerInstalled" for HP1910 in May, 2014 with a Prefer of 30.  4 of them have May 1st as their date, 2 of them have May 2nd.  You left out the May 2nd records.  Other than that, this result set matches your expected results and should work for larger datasets, I believe.

Comment: Increadible, I have also figured out just now, and got the same conclusion. Extend the WHERE clause in the EXISTS to narrow down and match exactly the row within our group of data, and not within the entire table.

Comment: my extension to your original solution was only this, which also works fine:   ... (exists (select 1 from r1 where Manufacturer = r.Manufacturer and dateof = r.DateOF and Status = 'ComputerNew') and r.status = 'ComputerInstalled') or
        (exists (select 1 from r1 where Manufacturer = r.Manufacturer and dateof = r.DateOF and status = 'ComputerOld') and r.status = 'ComputerUninstalled') ...

Comment: Thank you @DeadZone and JonSenchyna and everybody for this, i would hug you guys, if you were here!

Comment: Just a quick note...  I added an "EffDate" column to include just the month and year.  If you use DateOf instead of EffDate, then you will get different results if you have multiple records within the same month but on different days.  This is likely why my result set returned 2 additional records that your expected set did not.  If that's what you want, great.  But your explanation said to compare by month.

Comment: You are right, thats a typo from my pathetic trying. I need the month only, so EffDate the way to go!

Comment: Rather than posting a new answer, I cleaned up your query a bit.  Both of your `EXISTS` clauses contained shared filters.  I combined the filtering by seqnum = 1 and filtering by Status to a single `EXISTS` clause to make the SQL much more concise (and drop the extra CTE).

Comment: @DeadZone Isnt there a typo in the SELECT ? ...  WHERE   R.Manufacturer = R.Manufacturer ... it should be  WHERE   T.Manufacturer = R.Manufacturer

Comment: Yes.  Jon edited my answer to clean it up and introduced a bug.  I will roll back his edits if I can.  I've never tried to do that before.

Answer (score 1):

I think this ought to give you what you're looking for:

```
WITH sq AS
( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Manufacturer,DateOF ORDER BY Prefer) AS RankPrefer
  FROM table1
)
SELECT *
FROM   sq
WHERE  RankPrefer <= (SELECT TOP 1 RankPrefer FROM sq WHERE Status != 'ComputerNew' ORDER BY RankPrefer)
```

[Here is the SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99711/7).

Comment: Your solution works with this exact dataset, but that is simply due to what values are in the Prefer column.  If, for instance, 'ComputerUninstalled' had a Prefer value of 27, your solution would return all 'ComputerNew' and 'ComputerUninstalled' rows.  Also, if 'ComputerOld' had the lowest Prefer value, your solution does not include all 'ComputerUninstalled' rows.

Comment: @DeadZone Thank you for the query, but it indeed it just for this dataset.

Comment: Based on the new edits to the question, I have submitted a new answer.